# ChartJS Datalabels plugin and negative numbers

Tags: chart.js

**Issue:** I'm using the Datalabels plugin for Chartjs on a pie chart. It's working. Up until I feed it a negative number. The label only appears for positive numbers.

**Live Sample:** [roi.fyi](https://roi.fyi) (pie chart, charts tab)

**Details:**

It would appear that only positive values are accessible by the formatter.

I'm using ***options.plugins.datalabels.formatter*** to append a label.

The function accepts two numbers: investment and profit.

I've narrowed the issue down to just the following:

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

If **profit** is positive, I see log entries for both numbers. Can be formatted fine.

If **profit** is negative, I see log entries for only the positive number.

Edit: not solved exactly but found a simple enough work-around (see below).

Comment: Couple clarifications: Appears that the log entries append every time you hover. That's why there are so many. But still no log entries for negative. And, accessing the value using value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex]; does not work either.

Comment: Please provide a working sample because when I try it, its working just fine

Comment: @LeeLenalee thanks for hopping in. Here's a direct link with a negative value: https://roi.fyi/?qty=$700&hypothetical=$500 ... and here's an annotated screencap of what I'm seeing ... https://www.evernote.com/l/ANqn7UrFidxMnL5NEKx34obUivGrYCb-4Pk

Comment: Cant help you with that since I cant see what you are doing, as I said for me its working fine so without any repro it will be hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head against the table for a few hours it seems that this may just be the intended behavior of datalabels.

I managed to "solve" it pretty simply like this:

```
 profit = profit.replaceAll("-","");
```

The negative can be added back in later using the formatter. In my case, I use a different data object when profit is negative, color it red, and change the "profit" heading to "loss". Solved well enough!